# Using SceneKit within a Cocoa Application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, scenekit

Is it possible to use SceneKit for GPU accelerated graphics within a cocoa Application?

I'm looking for a way to do 2D animations in a PowerPoint like application, and not sure which direction to take to have GPU accelerated animations.

Picked up xCode about a week ago and went straight into swift with no Objective-C background. Didn't find any information on the topic, hoping to get this answered here.

[image]

Comment: If you are after a 2D game, then you must go with SpriteKit, if you want 3D, go with SceneKit.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot depicts the template selection in the project creator. What template you use has no impact on what features is possible in your application. It is perfectly possible to create a Cocoa app and simply drag and drop a `SCNView` and set it to run a SceneKit scene.

That being said, SceneKit or SpriteKit is definitely overkill just for doing "2D animations like in PowerPoint". You should look into Core Animation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html